# LM_TranslateLayer:DrawMe(moho, view) error

Tags: lua, updates

this is old code (Lua 5.1)

```
if (self.wiggleMode == self.LAYER_MODE) then
        if (self.wiggleChannel == self.TRANS_MODE) then
            LM_TranslateLayer:DrawMe(moho, view)
```

i have try change to lua 5.3 but error on:

```
LM_TranslateLayer:DrawMe(moho, view)
```

error: attempt to index global 'LM_TranslateLayer' (a nil value)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `LM_TranslateLayer` comes from an external library that is loaded via `require`. Make sure that this library does define global symbols.

In Lua 5.1, `require` automatically defined a global table to hold the module's content. So, `require"foo" defined`foo`.

In Lua 5.2 this changed and the idiom is now `local foo = require"foo"`.

Check how the library that defines `LM_TranslateLayer` is loaded.